# компиляция с помощью cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x

Компилирую питоновский файл cx_freeze на машине, где осуществлялась компиляция все работает прекрасно без всяких ошибок, а стоит запустить программу на другом пк, то вылезает следующая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом путь к библиотеке остается таким, какой был на первой машин, где компилировали файл, т.е при запуске скрипта на другой машине почему-то имя пользователя и все остальное не изменяется. Хотя я запускаю скрипт на совсем другой машине и логично, что имя пользователя совсем другое. Я думаю из-за этого и ошибка

Comment: pip install pyinstaller                                                                                           pyinstaller my_script.py

Comment: Александр, при pyinstaller тоже ошибки вылезают, только другие